# Take permutations $\sigma, \tau \in S_5$. Define $\sigma\sim\tau$ if $\sigma \tau^{-1} \in S_3$. Find equivalence class of $(4,5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Taking what the title says I want to find what the equivalence of class of $(4,5)$ is where $(4,5)$ is the permutation that maps 4 to 5, and 5 to 4.

To clarify $S_3$ is the set of all permutations of $\{ 1,2,3 \}$ and 
$S_5$ is the set of all permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Attempt at a solution: It is clear to me that $(4,5) \sim (4,5)$ since
$(4,5) (4,5)$ gives the identity which is in $S_n$ for all $n$. However, I
am stuck because I don't know how to come up with an exhaustive list or show that (4,5) is the only such permutation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha = (4.5)$. Suppose $\beta \in S_3$, then $\alpha \sim \beta \alpha$ since:

$$
\alpha (\beta \alpha)^{-1} = \alpha (\alpha^{-1} \beta^{-1}) = \beta^{-1} \in S_3
$$

Thus the equivalence class of $\alpha$ contains $\{\beta \alpha | \beta \in S_3 \}$.

On the other hand suppose $\beta \not \in S_3$, then $a \not \sim \beta \alpha$ since $\alpha(\beta \alpha)^{-1}=\beta^{-1} \not \in S_3$.

Since every element of $S_5$ can be written $\beta \alpha$ for some $\beta$, the equivalence class of $\alpha$ is exactly  $\{\beta \alpha | \beta \in S_3 \}$.